# How data can be bound in windows phone 8

Tags: c#

I want to bind the data in to list, the data can be parsed through xml and stored in local variables.

Next I want to bind these data in to list and stored in isolated storage. Please help me out.

```
 if (e.Result != null)
  {
                string serviceDate, name, taskname;
                XDocument doc;
                doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
    foreach (var absentDate in doc.Element("Classworks").Descendants("Classwork"))
                {
                    serviceDate = absentDate.Element("ClassworkDate").Value.ToString();
                    name = absentDate.Element("Subject").Value.ToString();
                    taskname = absentDate.Element("Task").Value.ToString();
                }


            }
            else
            {
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps you need to perform approximately :

1. Create a model to represent single data in List, say it `MyModel`. If `MyModel` property values is not static (can be changed at runtime), you may also need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the model.
2. Create a property of type `ObservableCollectoin<MyModel>`, say it `MyItemsSource`
3. Put a `LongListSelector` or similar user control that capable of displaying multiple data on the Page. Bind the control's `ItemsSource` to `MyItemsSource` property
4. Set the Page's `DataContext` properly.
5. Populate `MyItemsSource` in code, you can do this in `foreach` part shown in question.
6. Later, when you need to save the data to IsolatedStorage, the data is available in `MyItesSource` property. Just save it.

---

**Step 1**

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string ClassworkDate { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Task { get; set; }
}
```

**Step 2**

```
public ObservableCollection<MyModel> MyItemsSource { get; set; }
```

**Step 4**

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MyItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<MyModel>();
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

**Step 5**

```
foreach (var absentDate in doc.Element("Classworks").Descendants("Classwork"))
{
    serviceDate = absentDate.Element("ClassworkDate").Value.ToString();
    name = absentDate.Element("Subject").Value.ToString();
    taskname = absentDate.Element("Task").Value.ToString();
    var newModel = new MyModel{
                                 ClassworkDate = serviceDate,
                                 Subject = name,
                                 Task = taskname
                               };
    MyItemsSource.Add(newModel);
}
```

Above are codes related to logic in steps I explained before. With those codes setup, your data is ready to be bound. Note that in this example I didn't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` for brevity.

Comment: can u give me logic if u can ?it will be helpful for me

Comment: see the logic in my update. The rest is pick a user control to display the data. Documentation on how to bind the control must be available widely on internet.